# how to open beyond compare from java program give two files as input and store the result file somewhere

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to actually have a batch job.
I have tried opening simple programs like notepad in java but I am not aware how to open beyond compare
I need to open beyond compare from java code and give two files as input and give the result file stored locally and then later on find the percentage of similarity.
Any link would be of great help.

Here is what i have tried so far

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\BCompare.exe",
                file1path, file2path,"/qc=bin", "\\silent");
        Process ps;
         try {
                ps = processBuilder.start();
                OutputStream os = ps.getOutputStream();
                os.close();

                InputStream inputStream = ps.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                for (String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null; line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {

                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                ps.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Exit value :" + ps.exitValue());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



}
```

But it just prints exit value and program terminates

Comment: See the example [here](https://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?command_line_reference.html) on how to open Beyond Compare with parameters.

Comment: can someone please help me with java code

Comment: I have tried the below code

Answer (score 0):

[image: Beyond Compare Dialog Box]

If you are opening the beyond compare, the file names need to be select for comparison.
The left file and Right file need to be choose to be compare.

Comment: I need to open beyond compare from java program and pass files as input ,need to do it through code not manually